# Export and Import vTiger data and/or CRM Settings

Tags: vtiger

We need to set up a couple vTiger instances for user training and to test add-ons and CRM Settings (like: workflow, custom fields, picklists and custom functions, etc).

For example, rather than toy around in the a production environment for a major release of a new workflow, we need to develop it and it's new add-ons, custom fields, picklists, custom functions, etc. in a development environment, then 'promote' it to the production environment when we know its working.

The only thing I'm able to find on the internet were answers that seemed to be complete database export and imports, or migrating from one version to another.

I looked through the vTiger database schema and through most of the mySQL tables but found mostly pick list tables.

I think what I'm asking is, would anybody have the SQL to export only the configuration OR data tables from vTiger?

Thank you.